# Method called BEFORE orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

After the orientation changes, this method is called:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

But how do I take action **BEFORE** the guidance change? I need it before it changes, I save some things in SQLite.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You just can do your logic before `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);`.

Comment: @p.alexey wow, how I did not think of that before, hahaha, ty

Answer (score 0):

Your activity calls that onCreate() with different execution params in every orientation changes. But you can handle those changes by configuring `configChanges` tag in the manifest file.

For example, the following manifest code declares an activity that handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

you can find all the details about this configChanges by navigating this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes android official documentation.

You can use this knowledge and do what you want when triggering this method while orientation changes.